# Column auto does not adjust when use scroll X

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, datatables

When I use Data Table when I click tab column does not re-size as image
column and row does not show the same column

```
  var table12 = window.jQuery('#example_personal').DataTable({

        "scrollX": "100%",
        "ordering": true,
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

`sScrollX` instead of `scrollX`

```
var table12 = window.jQuery('#example_personal').DataTable({

    "scrollX": "100%",
    "ordering": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

});
```

Source: [datatable doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure if this will work but please try redrawing your table after clicking on tab.

Something like this

```
$('#example_personal').DataTable().draw();
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: still not work.
I loaded data table on the first load page. But do not when click tab
When click tab just only show data table

Comment: Did you tried re drawing the table when the tab is shown? i mean m not sure , just confirming

Comment: Yes I tried re drawing when click show tab as your comment.